# JQuery Panorama Viewer Inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to use the JQuery Panorama Viewer from http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/panorama_viewer_demo.html inside a Bootstrap modal. The site is an MVC C# solution with Bootstrap v3.1.1.

A map is displayed with pins on it. Clicking on a pin does an AJAX request, loads the image in the modal using the Panorama Viewer and displays it.

The index page makes the AJAX request.

Here is the HTML for the modal on the index page:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
```

Here is the JavaScript on the index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pin').tooltip();
        //every time pin is clicked
        $('.pin').click(function () {
            //store id of pin in js object
            var pin = {
                id: $(this).data("id")
            };
            //perform ajax request
            $.ajax({
                //use get type
                type: 'GET',
                //use razor function to bind it to controller function
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPanaramic")',
                //attach store id object
                data: pin,
                //method ran with success
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#modal').html(result);
                    $('#modal').modal('show');
                },
                //method ran with failure
                error: function(error) {
                    $('#modal').html('<div class="modal-header">Failed to get panaramic for this pin</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The panoramic page is called from an AJAX request from the index page.

Here is the HTML for the modal on the panoramic page:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">@Model.GetTitle()</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="panorama">
                <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/img/site-plans/{0}", @Model.GetFileName()))">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript on the panoramic page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#panorama").panorama_viewer({
        animationTime: 0,
        easing: "ease",
        overlay: false,
        repeat: @Model.FullRotate.ToString().ToLower()
    });
</script>
```

When I load the page up, the image inside the modal is always display:none

Comment: Can you also add the modal html ?

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any more